# Как удалить куки в Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#

Программно в C#

Comment: Сервис-Свойства обозревателя-блок история просмотра-кнопка удалить

Comment: Мне нужно программно, забыл добавить в вопросе, сорри)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно найти папку, где IE хранит куки, и попробовать удалить каждый из файлов-куки.

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies);
string[] cookies = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);

foreach(string cookie in cookies) {
    try  {
        System.IO.File.Delete(cookie);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```